# Conditional PDF question!

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the below question and I'm a bit stuck on all of the definition stuff, I have a more specific question below, but I thought it would be best to give some context to my question. I'm pretty stuck on how to approach this so any help would be much appreciated!

Consider a binary communication channel in which the input $X$ is either $c$ or $−c$ with probabilities $1/3$ and $2/3$, respectively.

Here, $c≥0$ is a given constant.  The channel output is given by $Y=X+N$,where $N$ is a standard normal random variable. For parts (b) and (c), you should provide closed-form expressions for your answers in terms of the standard normal CDF, $Φ$.

so my logic is, to find the conditional PDF, I'm trying to find the joint PDF of $x$ and $y$ and divide it by the PDF of $X$

Now I have the PDF of X down, so I was trying to get the PDF of $Y$ which is $N+X$. I know $f_X(x)$ and $f_N(n)$ separately but how do I put them together to get the PDF of $Y$? Does it make sense for me to just add them together?
 AKA $f_Y(y)= f_X(x)+f_N(n)?$

(a)  Find  the  conditional  PDF $f_Y|X(y|x)$  of $Y$ given $X=x$.   What  kind  of random variable is this?

(b)  Find the marginal PDF $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$.

(c)  Find the conditional probability $P(X=c|Y >0)$.  What happens as $c$ gets larger?

Comment: Please cancel every "Thank you", every exclamation mark and every use of boldfaced characters.

Comment: Good, you got rid of the "thank you"s, now for the exclamation marks and the uses of boldface characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given that $X$ can be equal to $-c$ and $c$ only. If $X=c$, then $Y=N+c$ has normal distribution $N(c,1)$. And for this case 
$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y-c)^2/2}.$$

Find $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid -c)$ and then by total probability law
$$
f_Y(y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid c)\mathbb P(X=c)+f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid-c)\mathbb P(X=-c).
$$

For (c) use the definition of conditional probability.